# Avoiding variable not defined in php

Tags: php

> I have been using php for webapp development and constantly i come
>   across variable not defined or index not defined error/warning.

Usally we do check it by **isset(variable)  or empty()** . But the problem I
   is that I have to write code for checking my entire
 variables(which can be empty) null or not by functions isset(variable)
 or empty() ,this makes code ugly.

> Can anyone suggest any aother method rather than checking variables
>   before using it??

Comment: My suggestion is to *always* make sure a variable is assigned before it *can* be used - after this you only need to check for "isset" when reading from arrays, such as $POST, and can consider everything else a programming error. Quickly and uniformly extract $POST/GET data into variables (or another appropriate type), and use parameters/arguments to minimize global state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's best to always define your variables before use.

I normally declare my variables with a default value. So you always know its going to be defined.

Answer (score 0):

You should always define variables in php. But if you really want to do things wrong, you can always disable E_NOTICE in PHP:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
```